# How to process input one number at a time through a while loop

Tags: java, string, while-loop, int, java.util.scanner

My main method asks the user for an expression, an input that will be something like "5 4 +" or "6 4 + 8 /" with operands and operators separated by a space. I have a method that processes this input and gives the answer to what it equals. It loops through all the numbers inputted through a while loop that ends once `scnr.hasNext() == true`, or when the errorMessage isn't null. Currently, `scnr.hasNext()` is becoming false sooner than its supposed to, causing the loop to only read the first number, and then end. It is becoming false because I try to store `scnr.nextInt()` into a variable. I need for it to take just the first number, and leave the rest, which I think will keep `scnr.hasNext()` true. Here is my entire method

```
public static Number evaluateExpression(String expr) {
        int var = 0;
        String input = "";

        String tooFewOperands = "Too few operands";
        String unKnownOperator = "Unknown operator:";
        String tooManyOperands = "Too many operands.";

        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
        String errMsg = null;

        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(expr);

        while (scnr.hasNext() && errMsg == null) {
            if (scnr.hasNextInt()) {
                var = scnr.nextInt();                           //Problematic line
                System.out.println("Operand read: " + var);
                stack.push(var);
            } else {
                input = scnr.next();
                if (checkValidOperator(input) == input.toCharArray()[0]) {
                    System.out.println("Operator read: " + input);
//                    stack.push(var);
                    if (stack.size() >= 2) {
                        execute(stack, input.toCharArray()[0]);
                    } else {
                        errMsg = tooFewOperands;
                    }
                } else {
                    errMsg = unKnownOperator + " " + input + " ";
                }
            }
            System.out.println("------ Stack state -----");
            System.out.println(stack.toString());
            System.out.println(scnr.hasNext());
        }
        if (errMsg != null) {
            System.out.println("Failed evaluation of |" + expr + "|\n" + errMsg);
            return null;
        }
        if (stack.size() > 1) {
            System.out.println("Failed evaluation of |" + expr + "|\n" + tooManyOperands + stack.toString());
            return null;
        } else {
            return stack.peek();
        }
    }
```

Notice that `Scanner scnr` is initialized with `String expr`, I think my teacher hinted at that allowing me to read individual tokens from the `scnr`. She said "Initialize a scanner using expr as a parameter to its constructor, which will allow you to read tokens from the expression." I've never initialized a Scanner with something other than `System.in`. She also specified that to make this method I should "Write a loop that will run as long as the scanner has input (hasNext) and error message is null." So that is what the while condition has to be.

Answer (score 0):

In general When you make a Scanner object for both String types and Numerical types it occurs (or at least it has happened to me).

What I done was to use `var = Integer.parseInt(scnr.nextLine());` instead.

Hope it help you.

Comment: Tried that, still made the loop end early.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with the structure of your `Scanner` code.

The only observation would be that this line looks odd:

```
if (checkValidOperator(input) == input.toCharArray()[0])
```

What's the implementation of `checkValidOperator`?

This bare bones version appears to work without any issues. Compare this to your version to see if you can identify which elements might be causing the problem.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String expr = "6 4 + 8 /";

    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(expr);

    String errorMsg = null;

    while (scnr.hasNext() && errorMsg == null)
    {
        if (scnr.hasNextInt())
        {
            int var = scnr.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Operand: " + var);
        } 
        else
        {
            String operator = scnr.next();
            if (isOperator(operator))
            {
                System.out.println("Operator: " + operator);
            } 
            else
            {
                errorMsg = "Unknown Operator: " + operator;
            }
        }
    }
}

static boolean isOperator(String op)
{
    return op.length() == 1 && "+-*/".indexOf(op) >= 0;
}
```